# Swift UIView Constraint Constant Height Changing Time Getting LayoutConstraints Warning

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am Implemented UIView Inside `storyboard` with constant height 90. Inside this UIView I have two `UIView height 25` and another one `UICollectionView 54`. Now, I am trying to reduce base UIView height 90 to 35 programmatically but I am getting `LayoutConstraints` Warning. Provide some solution for proper method.

Below Code I am using

```
BottomGalleryHeight.constant = 90 // Changing to 35
photoGalleryView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

My Warning Error

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282679360 UIView:0x102f30880.height == 25   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282679450 UIView:0x102f306a0.height == 35   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2826794a0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x102f30880]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x102f306a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28267e210 V:[UIView:0x102f30880]-(10)-[UICollectionView:0x10385e000]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28267d450 V:[UICollectionView:0x10385e000]-(1)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x102f306a0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282679360 UIView:0x102f30880.height == 25   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Can you show us how it is supposed to look visually?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I updated my question. There is white color base UIView 90 height and Inside base UIView top blue color UIView 25 height and Bottom Collection View 54 height. The height I gave constant in storyboard layout. But code base I am changing Base UIView (white) Initially 35 and 90.

Comment: You need to change the height constraint of inner UIView and the collectionView as well so it adjust within the height of outer view i.e. 35.

Comment: Please show all constraints that you create to the views. (You can add screenshot of IB)

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: @PGDev. Thank you buddy, I will try and update you here.

Comment: @PGDev same error I am facing. I changed Inner View constraints but I am getting same issues.

Comment: What should be the height of inner views when you set the outer view height to 35?

Comment: @PGDev. I posted my working answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below working code for adjusting constraints constant height

```
// to update height constant
photoGalleryView.updateConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, constant: 20.0)

extension UIView {    

    func updateConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, constant: CGFloat) -> Void {
        if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == attribute}.first) {
            constraint.constant = constant
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get that working,

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var innerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        outerViewHeight.constant = 35.0
        innerViewHeight.constant = 10.0
        collectionViewHeight.constant = 25.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much such a great help. btw below posted answer also working fine. which one I need to mark it right? :)

Comment: That's totally your choice. The one which you think is a better solution should be accepted.